# If $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^da_i\left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(x+j)\right)$ is linear, what is its constant term?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, interpolation

**Question**: Fix $d,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0\leq m\leq d$ and define
$$P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^da_i\left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(x+j)\right),$$
where each $a_i$ is a constant, $a_m=0$. Suppose that, after expansion, $P(x)=c-x$ for some constant $c$. Show that $c=\frac{m}{d}-d$.

I obtained a rough solution by evaluating $P\left(-(d+k)\right)$ for each $0\leq k\leq m$, which yields $m+1$ linear relations on $a_0,\dots, a_{m-1}$ and $c$, from which one can then solve by scaling and subtracting. However, I am hoping for a cleaner, more succinct answer (in fact, one might even be able to use the above approach in a neater way than I did).

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: @darijgrinberg this arose from a geometry problem I’ve been thinking about for a while, it’s not from any source (at least not that I know of!)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have anything overly nice either, but maybe you can improve on it. My ansatz is that $a_i = \left(-1\right)^i \left(\lambda \dbinom{d}{i} + \mu \dbinom{d-1}{i}\right)$ for all $i$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two constants that need to be determined. Indeed, this is the general form of $a_i$ for which $P\left(x\right)$ is linear in $x$. (This follows from some linear algebra and finite difference yoga -- let me know if you need more details.) Now you should be able to find $\lambda$ and $\mu$ from the conditions $a_m = 0$ and $P\left(x\right) = c-x$.

Comment: What is the geometry problem, though?

Comment: @darijgrinberg If you want to write that up, if it is a complete solution, I will accept it since I doubt there is a much sleeker way to do it... This problem actually came up when considering the intersection of planes along a curve, but the source of the problem is not helpful to solving this, in this case, unfortunately...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a detailed write-up of the solution sketched in @darijgrinberg 's comment.

**Summary of solution:** the problem can be restated as saying that the $a_i$'s
are the coordinates of $P(x)=c-x$ in a certain basis. So we only need to compute the
coordinates of $1$ and $x$ in this basis to obtain the $a_i$ in terms of $c$.

**Detailed solution :** let $\beta_{d,k}(x)=\prod_{j=k}^{d+k-1}(x+j)$ (so that $P=\sum_{k=0}^d a_k\beta_{d,k}(x)$) and ${\cal B}_d=(\beta_{d,0},\beta_{d,1},\ldots,\beta_{d,d})$.

**Lemma 1.** ${\cal B}_d$ forms a basis of ${\mathbb R}_d[x]$, the space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$.

**Proof of lemma 1.** It will suffice to show that the members of ${\cal B}_d$ are linearly independent. So suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^d \lambda_k \beta_{d,k}=0$
for some scalars $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$. Evaluating at $-d$, we see that $\lambda_0=0$. Next, evaluating at $-(d+1)$, we see that $\lambda_1=0$, etc.

Our goal is now to compute the coordinates of $1$ and $x$ in the basis ${\cal B}_d$. The idea is to iterate the difference operator $\Delta$ defined by $\Delta(Q)=Q(x+1)-Q(x)$ for a polynomial $Q$. We will use two well-known facts on $\Delta^{i}(Q)$ which are straightforward to check by induction on $i$ once stated.

**Fact 1.** $\Delta^{i}(Q)=\sum_{k=0}^{i}(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}Q(x+k)$.

**Fact 2.** If the two leading monomials of $Q$ are $ax^d+bx^{d-1}$ and $i\leq d-1$, then the two leading monomials of $\Delta^i(Q)$ are $(i!\binom{d}{i}a)x^{d-i}+(\frac{i}{2}(i+1)!\binom{d}{i+1}a+i!\binom{d-1}{i}b)x^{d-i-1}$.

Combining the two facts for $i=d$, we deduce

$$
(d!)a=\Delta^d(Q)=\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-k}\binom{d}{k}Q(x+k). \label{1}\tag{1}
$$

And for $i=d-1$, we deduce similarly

\begin{align}
&((d!)a)x+\bigg(\frac{d-1}{2}d!a+(d-1)!b\bigg)=\Delta^{d-1}(Q) \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(-1)^{d-1-k}\binom{d-1}{k}Q(x+k). \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

Notice that in the LHS of \eqref{2}, the constant term can be rewritten
as $(d!)a \times \rho$ where $\rho=\frac{d-1}{2}+\frac{b}{da}$. Subtracting $\rho$ times \eqref{1} from \eqref{2}, we deduce :

\begin{align}
((d!)a)x= \sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-1-k}\bigg(\binom{d-1}{k}+\rho\binom{d}{k}\bigg)Q(x+k) \label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

(since $\dbinom{d-1}{d}=0$). We now apply this context to $Q=\beta_{d,0}$. Then we have $a=1,b=\frac{d(d-1)}{2}$ and hence $\rho=d-1$, so that \eqref{1} becomes

$$
1=\frac{(-1)^d}{d!} \sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^k \binom{d}{k}\beta_{d,k} \label{1'}\tag{1'}
$$

and \eqref{3} becomes

$$
x= \sum_{k=0}^{d}\frac{(-1)^{d-1-k}}{d!}\bigg(\binom{d-1}{k}+(d-1)\binom{d}{k}\bigg)\beta_{d,k} \label{3'}\tag{3'}
$$

Note that $\binom{d-1}{k}+(d-1)\binom{d}{k}=\big(d-\frac{k}{d}\big)\binom{d}{k}$, so that \eqref{3'} simplifies to

$$
x=\frac{(-1)^d}{d!}\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{k+1}\big(d-\frac{k}{d}\big)\binom{d}{k}\beta_{d,k} \label{3''}\tag{3''}
$$

Combining \eqref{1'} and \eqref{3''}, we deduce

$$
a_k=\frac{(-1)^d}{d!}(-1)^{k}\binom{d}{k}\bigg(c-\big(\frac{k}{d}-d\big)\bigg) \ (0\leq k\leq d) \label{4}\tag{4}
$$
and your claim immediately follows.

Comment: (+1) Your (4) is verified by Maple.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! I've made some simplifications and corrections.

Answer (score 4):

**Some thoughts**

Clearly, $d\ge 1$.
Let $x = -(m-1), -m, -(m+1), \cdots, -(d-1)$ respectively to get
\begin{align}
P(1-m) &= c + m - 1, \\
P(-m) &= c + m, \\
P(-m - 1) &= c + m+1, \\
&\cdots\cdots\\
P(-d+1) &= c + d - 1.
\end{align}
Then we have (weighted sum of the equations above)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} P(-m - k + 1)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{d-m} (c + m + k - 1) (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}. \tag{1}
$$

*Claim 1*: It holds that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} P(-m - k + 1)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k} = 0.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

By (1) and Claim 1, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} (c + m + k - 1) (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k} = 0$$
which results in
$$c = -m + 1 - \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} k (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}}
= -m + 1 - (d+1)\frac{d-m}{d} = \frac{m}{d} - d$$
where we have used the identity (see 26.3.10 in https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.3)
$$(-1)^N \binom{M}{N} = \sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^k \binom{M+1}{k}, \quad 0\le N \le M$$
to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k} = (-1)^{d-m}\binom{d}{d-m}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} k (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k} = (d+1)\frac{d-m}{d}(-1)^{d-m}\binom{d}{d-m}. \tag{2}$$
(The proof of (2) is given at the end.)

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Claim 1*: We have
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} P(-m - k + 1)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
=\ & \sum_{k=0}^{d-m} \sum_{i=0}^d a_i\left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j)\right)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
=\ & \sum_{i=0}^d a_i \sum_{k=0}^{d-m} \left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j)\right)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
=\ & \sum_{i=0}^d a_i A_i
\end{align}
where
$$A_i = \sum_{k=0}^{d-m} \left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j)\right)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}.$$
It suffices to prove that $A_i = 0$ for all $i \ne m$.

We split into three cases:

1. $m = d$: For $0\le i < m$, we have
   $$A_i = \prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-d + 1+j) = 0.$$
2. $m = 0$: For $1\le i\le d$, noting that $\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j) = 0$ for $i + 1 \le k \le d$, we have
   \begin{align}
   A_i &= \sum_{k=0}^{d} \left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}( - k + 1+j)\right)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^i \left(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}( - k + 1+j)\right)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^i \frac{(d+i-k)!}{(i-k)!}(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
   &= d! \sum_{k=0}^i (-1)^k \binom{d+1}{k} \binom{d+i-k}{i-k}\\
   &= 0
   \end{align}
   where we have used the identity (see @arindam mitra's answer:
   [Prove combinatorial identity using inclusion/exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035983/prove-combinatorial-identity-using-inclusion-exclusion-principle))
   $$\sum_{k=0}^M (-1)^k \binom{N}{k}\binom{N + r - k}{M - k} = 0, \quad 0 \le r \le M-1$$
   to get (let $M = i$, $N = d + 1$, $r = i - 1$)
   $$\sum_{k=0}^i (-1)^k \binom{d+1}{k} \binom{d+i-k}{i-k} = 0.$$
3. $1 \le m \le d - 1$: If $0\le i < m$, clearly $\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j) = 0$ and hence $A_i = 0$.

If $m < i \le d$, I $\color{blue}{\textrm{GUESS}}$ $A_i = 0$.

*Remark*: With the help of Maple, $\color{blue}{\textrm{it appears that}}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} \Big(\prod_{j=i}^{d+i-1}(-m - k + 1+j)\Big)(-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}
= (-1)^{d-m}\binom{d}{m} \prod_{0\le k \le d, \, k\ne m} (i-k). \tag{2}$$
How to prove it?

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of (2)*: If $d-m = 0$, it is obvious. If $d-m\ge 1$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{d-m} k (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{d-m} k (-1)^k\binom{d+1}{k}\\
&= (d+1) \sum_{k=1}^{d-m} (-1)^k \binom{d}{k-1}\\
&= -(d+1) \sum_{j=0}^{d-m-1} (-1)^j \binom{d}{j}\\
&= -(d+1)(-1)^{d-m-1}\binom{d-1}{d-m-1}\\
&= (d+1)\frac{d-m}{d}(-1)^{d-m}\binom{d}{d-m}.
\end{align}
We are done.