# Binomial coefficient identity with alternating summands

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Is there a nice closed form for

$\sum_{k=0}^{l} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{l-k}.$

I feel like there must be but I cannot find it.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by proving that: $$\binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{l-k} = \binom{n}{l}\binom{l}{k}$$

Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{l} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{l-k} &= \sum_{k=0}^{l} (-1)^k \binom{n}{l}\binom{l}{k} \\
&= \binom{n}{l} \left(1 - 1\right)^l = 0
\end{align}